# PHPMyAdmin input area got longer

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was managing my database in PHPMyAdmin then suddenly the input area got longer like this and i couldn't write anything. I made it as a foreign key to other table before. Does anyone know why is this happening? Thankyou.

[image]

Comment: MySQL is a database, a server application that stores data; it doesn't have any UI. I'm guessing this is something like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench?

Comment: ah yes, i'm sorry, this is phpmyadmin @IMSoP